# EF Code First - Seeding after Deleting and then Creating database

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I'm trying to force EF Code First to re-initialize the database. My first thoughts were to call:

```
dbContext.Database.Delete();    
dbContext.Database.Create();
```

This creates a new database but the seeding strategy (set using Database.SetInitializer<>) is ignored. I'm doing the above in the Application_Start method. Any ideas?

I have also tried:

```
dbContext.Database.Initialize(true);
```

Comment: Can you post your Database.SetInitializer<> code?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create your own DatabaseInitializer that inherits from DropCreateDatabaseAlways.

An example of this would be.

```
public class MyInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EmployeeContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(EmployeeContext context)
    {
        context.Employees.Add(new Employee() {FirstName = "Marcy"});
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}

public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
{
    static EmployeeContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MyInitializer()); // using my own initializer
    }

    public IDbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I've already done that. But I can't force it to run (without changing the model.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to overcome this:

1. Add a flag in your context initializer

   public bool WasSeeded = false;
2. Create a public method in your initializer and put your seed code there. I made sure to use only AddOrUpdate or other upsert methods, i.e. check the data is not in the DB before:

   context.Students.AddOrUpdate

At the end set the flag to true

1. After you initialize the context, check the flag and if it is false run the logic manually:

   if (!initializer.WasSeeded)
   {
        initializer.SeedAndUpsert(context);
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
Database.SetInitializer(new CustomInitializer()); //CustomInitializer contains the overriding Seed method

using (var context = new CustomDatabaseContext())
{
    context.Database.Initialize(force: true);
}
```